# MS Test .orderedtest file details

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium, mstest, ordered-test

I'm using scaffolding to dynamically generate UI tests with MS Test and Selenium.  I've generated the selenium tests just fine and want to generate .orderedtest files to order the test.
The .orderedtest file is xml based:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <OrderedTest name="CRUD_VendorRemark" storage="c:\users\mikeb\documents\visualstudio2010\projects\edimanagementqa\edimanagement.uitesting\orderedtests\crud_vendorremark.orderedtest" id="ca31cb3f-6802-46c5-9f17-53c3632b6681" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
        <TestLinks>
          <TestLink id="d20974aa-59c6-fb5f-2567-dfff025078f2" name="CreateNew_Invalid_ErrorMessagePresent" storage="..\bin\debug\edimanagement.uitesting.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <TestLink id="2408cc97-59b6-7344-e5e1-0dd05592a6d8" name="CreateNew_Valid_SuccessMessagePresent" storage="..\bin\debug\edimanagement.uitesting.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <TestLink id="02528772-e3b7-3102-893c-808b3b8c50a8" name="Edit_LastItemInvalid_ErrorMessagePresent" storage="..\bin\debug\edimanagement.uitesting.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <TestLink id="1c215986-cfd9-9a57-9049-2f203199461f" name="Edit_LastItemValid_SuccessMessagePresent" storage="..\bin\debug\edimanagement.uitesting.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <TestLink id="16cd31fb-a73b-75b3-a886-48e4b0e4697b" name="Delete_LastItem_SuccessMessagePresent" storage="..\bin\debug\edimanagement.uitesting.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </TestLinks>
</OrderedTest>
```

It seems the individual test methods are being referenced by the id="guid", but I don't see it anywhere else in the project.
Any insight as to how the tests are being referenced?
Can the .orderedtest file be generated purely by writing xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They need to be loaded & resolved inside the test project. The ID is per-test type. if you look at a manual test, or other file based test type, you'll see theres a test ID guid element; it's pretty much a GUID.

However, for unit tests... well, thats a different conversation. I posted details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhopton/archive/2008/06/12/helpful-internals-of-trx-and-vsmdi-files.aspx) that should help you get to the end result that you need.